# Left join on interval of date range

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two dataframes

df1

| user_id | Date 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 |
| 2 | 2020-02-15 |
| 3 | 2022-03-02 |

and
df2

| user_id | entrance_date | exit_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-06-01 | null |
| 1 | 2008-01-01 | 2012-01-01 |
| 2 | 2010-02-02 | 2020-02-13 |
| 3 | 2011-01-01 | null |

I want to have the following

df1

| user_id | Date 1 | tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | True |
| 2 | 2020-01-15 | False |
| 3 | 2022-03-02 | True |

I have tried the following but it's not working:

```
df1 = df1.join(df2, "user_id", "left")
         .withColumn("tag",  F.when( F.col("Date1") >= F.col("entrance_date") & F.col("Date1") <= F.col("exist_date") | F.col("Date1") >= F.col("entrance_date") & F.col("exist_date").isnull), lit("True")).otherwise(lit("False"))
```

The tag column is constructed if for a user_id the Date 1 is between entrance_date and exist_date

Comment: How the tag column is constructed ?

Comment: The tag column is constructed if for a user_id   the Date 1 is between entrance_date and exist_date

Comment: @f.ivy Isn't 2020-01-15  between 2010-02-02 and 2020-02-13 ?

Comment: Sorry typo, i have modified it

Comment: @f.ivy Thanks, posted my answer now. Let me know if you face any issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to

1. Wrap the column names in `F.col('<colname>')`
2. Streamline your conditionals (if-else clauses)
3. Use `F.isnull()` instead of `is null`

Below code is untested but should do the trick

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F



df1 = df1 \
    .withColumn(
        'tag',
        F.when(
            F.col('Date 1') >= F.col('entrance_date'),
            F.when(
                (F.col('Date 1') <= F.col('exit_date')) | (F.isnull(F.col('exit_date'))),
                F.lit("True")
            ).otherwise(F.lit("False"))
        ).otherwise(F.lit("False"))
    )
```

**EDIT:**

In the case that a single user can have multiple rows in `df2`, our approach will be to left join `df1` to `df2` and then aggregate `df2` to a `user_id`, `Date 1` level with an aggregate on the computed column `tag`. Code below (along with typos corrected):

This has been tested and works as expected

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


df2 = df2.join(df1, "user_id", "left")
df2 = df2.withColumn(
    'tag',
    F.when(
        F.col('Date 1') >= F.col('entrance_date'),
        F.when(
            (F.col('Date 1') <= F.col('exit_date')) | (F.isnull(F.col('exit_date'))),
            F.lit(True)
        ).otherwise(F.lit(False))
    ).otherwise(F.lit(False))
)

result = df2.groupby(['user_id', 'Date 1']).agg(F.max("tag").alias("tag"))
```

Comment: it's returning False for user_id==1, it's considering only  this row 1 2008-01-01 2012-01-01

Comment: added an edit to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
df1.alias("df1").join(df2.alias("df2"), [F.col("df1.user_id")==F.col("df2.user_id")])\
.withColumn("Tag", F.when(F.col("df1.date_1").between(F.col("df2.entrance_date"), F.coalesce(F.col("df2.exit_date"), F.lit("2099-03-02").cast("date"))), "true").otherwise("false"))\
.groupBy("df1.user_id")\
.agg(F.first("date_1").alias("date_1"), F.sum(F.when(F.col("tag") == "true", 1).otherwise(0)).cast("boolean").alias("tag"))\
.show()
```

Input:

DF1-DF2

[image: DF1-DF2]

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: @Luuk Thanks - I'm aware of the same but manytimes people think that the output is not authentic/fake so I started posting screenshots. Nevertheless will use code blocks from now.

Answer (score 0):

@sud's answer is good. Personally I prefer to set the NULL end_date columns to something useful like '9999-12-31', assuming this means an 'open' end date. This tends to reduce complexity, especially when required to do more than one operation.

```
# fill the end_date NULLs
df_2 = df_2.withColumn('exit_date', 
  F.coalesce('exit_date', F.to_timestamp(F.lit('9999-12-31')))
)

df = df_1.join(df_2, on='user_id', how='inner')

# additional OR condition's not required
df.withColumn('tag',
  F.when(F.col('date_1').between(
    F.col('entrance_date'), F.col('exit_date')
  ), F.lit(True)).otherwise(F.lit(False))
).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the others, but in this case I prefer to use spark sql.

```
df1.join(df2, 'user_id', 'inner') \
  .withColumn('tag', f.expr("`Date 1` between entrance_date and coalesce(exit_date, '2999-12-31')")) \
  .groupBy('user_id') \
  .agg(f.first('Date 1').alias('Date 1'), f.first('tag').alias('tag')) \
  .show()

+-------+----------+-----+
|user_id|    Date 1|  tag|
+-------+----------+-----+
|      1|2023-01-01| true|
|      2|2020-02-15|false|
|      3|2022-03-02| true|
+-------+----------+-----+
```